# React TypeScript component with two different prop interfaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a React TypeScript component whose props is a union of two different interfaces. However, when I do so, I get the warning:

```
TS2339: Property 'color' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<Props>'
```

How can I create a React TypeScript component with a union of two different prop interfaces and at the same time am able to destructure those props? Thanks!

**sampleComponent.tsx:**

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface SamplePropsOne {
  name: string;
}

interface SamplePropsTwo {
  color: string;
}

type Props = SamplePropsOne | SamplePropsTwo;

const SampleComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ color, name }) => (
  color ? (
    <h1>{color}</h1>
  ) : (
    <h1>{name}</h1>
  )
);

export default SampleComponent;
```

[image]

Comment: why you don't want to pass only one type of props from parent component to `SampleComponent`? You can pass `<SampleComponent name={name} />` or `<SampleComponent name={color} />`.

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko, please don't take the component implementation details literally. The question is more about how to create a component that can accept a series of different prop interfaces.

Comment: I understand that you gave just an example. But what you want to create is not a component. It is like a fabric of components, that accepts type, data and then renders the desired component.

Answer (score 28):

Before TypeScript will let you read `name` or `color` off the union type, it needs some evidence that you're working with the correct type of Props (`SamplePropsOne` or `SamplePropsTwo`). There are a few standard ways to provide it with this.

One is by making the union a *tagged* union by introducing a property to distinguish branches of the union. This type checks just fine:

```
interface SamplePropsOne {
  type: 'one';
  name: string;
}

interface SamplePropsTwo {
  type: 'two';
  color: string;
}

type Props = SamplePropsOne | SamplePropsTwo;

const SampleComponent: React.FC<Props> = props => (
  props.type === 'one' ? (
    <h1>{props.name}</h1>
  ) : (
    <h1>{props.color}</h1>
  )
);
```

If you get the cases backwards (as I did when writing this!) then TypeScript will complain.

If the presence of a property is enough to distinguish the types, then you can use the `in` operator:

```
interface SamplePropsOne {
  name: string;
}
interface SamplePropsTwo {
  color: string;
}
type Props = SamplePropsOne | SamplePropsTwo;

const SampleComponent: React.FC<Props> = props => (
  'color' in props ? (
    <h1>{props.color}</h1>
  ) : (
    <h1>{props.name}</h1>
  )
);
```

If determining which type of object you have requires more complex logic, you can write a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). The key part is the "is" in the return type:

```
function isSampleOne(props: Props): props is SamplePropsOne {
  return 'name' in props;
}

const SampleComponent: React.FC<Props> = props => (
  isSampleOne(props) ? (
    <h1>{props.name}</h1>
  ) : (
    <h1>{props.color}</h1>
  )
);
```

It's also worth noting that because of the way structural typing works, there's no reason `props` in your example couldn't have both `name` *and* `color`:

```
const el = <SampleComponent name="roses" color="red" />;  // ok
```

If it's important to not allow this, you'll need to use some slightly fancier types:

```
interface SamplePropsOne {
  name: string;
  color?: never;
}
interface SamplePropsTwo {
  color: string;
  name?: never;
}
type Props = SamplePropsOne | SamplePropsTwo;
```

The ts-essentials library has an [`XOR` generic](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials#xor) that can be used to help construct exclusive unions like this.

Answer (score 18):

I think what you are looking for are [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).

Replace this line:

```
type Props = SamplePropsOne | SamplePropsTwo;
```

with this line:

```
type Props = SamplePropsOne & SamplePropsTwo;
```

- **Intersection types:** combine multiple interfaces/types into one
- **Union types:** choose one of multiple interfaces/types

**EDIT**

What you want is not possible (i think). What you could do is destructuring every type in a single line after casting `props`:

```
const SampleComponent: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  const { name } = props as SamplePropsOne;
  const { color } = props as SamplePropsTwo;

  return color ? <h1>{color}</h1> : <h1>{name}</h1>;
};
```

Comment: I want a user to be able to provide a `name` prop or a `color` prop, but not both.

Comment: @Jimmy oh, sorry. I edited the question. It's a bit more code but I dont think there is another option here. Also you might want to consider implementing 2 different components which use a 3 common component.

Comment: @ysfaran, Any idea to do this? -> "I want a user to be able to provide a name prop or a color prop, but not both." ? ,Thanks!

Comment: @Esther-I I think it should be clear from the answer. To break it down, you need to use union types: `type Props = { name: string } | { color: string }`. I don't know about your exact issue, so I can not answer it properly. Consider asking a new question!

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It was supposed to be directed to @Jimmy, he had the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Jimmy, Any idea to do this? -> "I want a user to be able to provide a name prop or a color prop, but not both." ? ,Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help

```js
interface SamplePropsOne {
  name: string;
  color: never;
}

interface SamplePropsTwo {
  name: never;
  color: string;
}

type Props = SamplePropsOne | SamplePropsTwo;

const SampleComponent = ({ color, name }: Props) => {
  console.log(color ? color : name);
}
```

ts playground link : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpwLYAcA2EAKUA9lgM4DyIKA3gFDLIiYQBcypYUoA5gNz3IERHEShsqAN2j8AvrVqhIsRCnTY8hEqQAqAdyLI6DJhlaMIUqPwZCRY9px6z5YAJ5YUmssgC8aTLgExGSUKAA+-upBWnpE-LRCIByRgQDCRNhEVOC+yAAU1ILCogA0jMzIMmxepACUvgB8hgKJpMIQAHQi3Hm2osgA-EV2yOLMtbJAA